# A generic function using templates with different input arguments and different return type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, overloading

Is there a way to avoid function overloading and write a more generic function using template? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
placement Detect::predict(Eigen::Array<double, rowSize, 1> &feature)
```

and

```
position Detect::predict(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<double>> &feature)
```

In the above, `placement` and `position` are ENUMS of with various categories.

How can I write this using `template`?

Comment: IMO there is no way to use the template in your functions.

Comment: Ok. So to clear my understanding, the input arguments and the return type should be same in order to use templates?

Comment: No the argument and return types doesn't have to be the same as the template argument, but there's just no simple or elegant way to make a single function that can handle both cases, which of the types (return or argument) should be templated? One or the other or both? How would you differentiate between the implementations? Overloading is the best way here as I see it, if there's code common between the two functions, put that common code in a third function that you can call instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you all.

Comment: Well you return type can be whatever you want but the input arguments should be related somehow. Maybe there is relation which I cannot see. If there were implementation of them I could say something more.

Comment: The code is little messy and it would not be a minimal code. If possible, can you please provide an example of how this could be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, starting from the code you posted, one cannot offer a solution that uses the same classes and names.
Anyway, maybe you can do what you are trying to do by relying on sfinae expressions.

As an example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value, char>
func(T) { return 'c'; }

template<typename T>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same<T, int>::value, int>
func(T) { return 42; }

int main() {
    static_assert(func(42) == 'c', "!");
    static_assert(func(.0) == 42, "!");
}
```

In the example above, `func` returns a `char` if the type of the argument is `int`, otherwise it returns an `int`.
You must simply adjust the types and the sfinae expressions according with your requirements.

**Note**

I'm not saying that the OP shouldn't go with overloading. Instead I think it would be better in this case.
This answer tries only to show how the OP can reach the target by using templates.

Comment: Thanks. Let me see if I can modify my code accordingly.

Comment: Downvoters: at least a comment would help knowing what the downvote is for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.
I presume you want to template your detect function with the container being passed in as the type.

What you need to do is relate the desired return type to the container type. If there is no existing fixed relationship you can use the type traits concept (I don't mean the type traits header used in another answer)

Basically you create a new template class that contains a typedef or using statement that will be used as the return type of your detect function. These return types can wrap the enum.

You specialise this trait class for each of the container types you need to use (may have to use template template parameters here)

Sorry I can't give example right now but will update answer when I have more time and a proper keyboard if you need more.

Comment: Thanks Rox. At present, there is no fixed relationship. I would appreciate if you could please provide an example.